# Xcode 8 Linker error with Framework, undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Can anybody help me with this 'Apple Mac O linker Error', builds are getting failed and I really don't have any clue..
I am using Mac Ox 10.11, the SDK is set to the Latest 10.0 OS and Deployment Target is 8.0.
Framework and user header search path are set to framework location..

Error is Below:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/syedmuhammadyasir/Documents/UrduRhymes/Urdu\ Rhymes/Frameworks'
ld: warning: ignoring file Urdu Rhymes/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x6C 0x69 0x6E 0x6B 0x20 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): Urdu Rhymes/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
      -[URHomeViewController adViewWillPresentBannerView] in URHomeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in URBaseViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in URBaseViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in URBaseViewController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[URHomeViewController adViewWillPresentBannerView] in URHomeViewController.o
      -[URBaseViewController getGADAdSize] in URBaseViewController.o
      -[URHomeViewController adViewWillPresentBannerView] in URHomeViewController.o
      -[URBaseViewController getGADAdSize] in URBaseViewController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeFullBanner", referenced from:
      -[URBaseViewController getGADAdSize] in URBaseViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you using any specific architecture or any third party for google ads?

Comment: using GoogleMobileAds.framework

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the "-ObjC" linker flag from the "Other Linker Flags" section of build settings.

Or

I suggest you to remove that framework and add two pods

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

and follow this [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

If you Integrating without CocoaPods.
Add the **ObjC** linker flag in your **Other Linker Settings** in your target's **build settings**

Comment: Tried linker flag but no success.